# Change the product type of an existing product in WooCommerce 3+

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, type-conversion, product

I need to change the woocommerce product type after creation with a function in my child theme i have tried this :

```
 wp_set_object_terms($product_id, 'variable', 'product_type', true);
```

My method is triggered after creation but the type still unchanged ?

Comment: You should add in your question your complete hooked function code, as your actual code is not testable… *"Your question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem"***.

Comment: i have tested after get product and save it the code work i think the problem is there is an asynchron call in the plugin hook

Comment: Using `wp_set_object_terms()`, doesn't always works for many reasons, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58345045/woocommerce-change-product-type-in-function … The answer below is based on [the save()](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.2.2/includes/admin/meta-boxes/class-wc-meta-box-product-data.php#L324-L431) function used when you save a product in backend

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since WooCommerce 3, to change the product type from an existing product, you can use the following:

```
/**
 * Change product type.
 *
 * @param int     $product_id       - The product id.
 * @param string  $new_product_type - The new product type
 */
 
// Get the correct product classname from the new product type
$product_classname = WC_Product_Factory::get_product_classname( $product_id, $new_product_type );

// Get the new product object from the correct classname
$new_product       = new $product_classname( $product_id );

// Save product to database and sync caches
$new_product->save();
```

Tested and works in all cases, because `wp_set_object_terms()`, doesn't works well for many reasons, see [this older related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58345045/woocommerce-change-product-type-in-function). The new product will keep all its existing data.

Useful reference: [`WC_Meta_Box_Product_Data` `save()` method](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.2.2/includes/admin/meta-boxes/class-wc-meta-box-product-data.php#L318-L431)

Comment: your solution work great but there is one problem the generale tab of woocommerce after creation is break i dont kno why ? also it seems that product isnt a copy of existing one

Comment: also change $product_classname to $classname

Comment: Ihave updated the code … I have tested my code, and the product keeps all data that can be used in the new product type.

Comment: ok i well accept please change the $product_classname to $classname

Comment: @MoradAngel The "downloadable" product option is not a product type, but a product property, so it's not related to this question. On creation, you can set all inventory properties as you like… Now  when I have changed the product type from an existing simple product to a variable product, the inventory settings are still the same.